# Remove subfolder name from url in wordpress as a subdomain

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Here's the deal... in a shared hosting, I created a subdomain like blog.mydomain.com in order to install wordpress, when i did that in cpanel it created a subfolder inside the root like public/blog.
So the installation goes well but, when I visit **blog.mydomain** url, it changes to **blog.mydomain.com/blog** I wanna remove the last */blog*, also it shows Can't find the page, but not as a error just like a post that doesn't exists.

In the codex page from wordpress it says that the first thing to do is go to dashboard > general panel and change the **box for WordPress address (URL)** and the **box for Site address (URL)** but in my general panel settings this options does not show up, I belive this is a thing from the installation.

I'm guessing that I can accomplish this from the .htaccess, btw here's the one that wordpress created:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Do I have to modify this .htaccess?? if so, how to do that?? or the one in the root folder, considering that the root one is for a laravel application which resides in the main domain.

This is the main .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#LARAVEL
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
#END LARAVEL

</IfModule>
```

Hope someone can help me, Thanx...

Answer (score 1):

1)login to admin of your website and update the website url to

```
 blog.mydomain.com
```

2)open the wp-config.php file in the root, find for

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

and make the changes and also update the functions.php file in theme folder.

3) update the website url in wp_options table in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1
open the wp-config.php file in the root, find for

define('WP_HOME','http://blog.mydomain.com/blog');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://blog.mydomain.com');

Step 2
Copy the "index.php" and ".htaccess" files from the new subdirectory into the root directory.

Step 3
Open the "index.php" file in the root directory with a text editor. Look for the line that says: 
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
Replace that line with this line: 
require('./blog/wp-blog-header.php');

Step 4
Open your Web browser to the following address site url blog.mydomain.com
admin url is blog.mydomain.com/blog/wp-admin